# Не выходит сделать ссылку

Tags: php

нужно из записей которые выводятся сделать ссылки на другой файл(записи выводятся нормально), но как начинаю делать из них ссылку оно не работает, точнее некорректно работает, появляется только одна ссылка, а записей то несколько как из них всех сделать ссылку на отдельный файл со своим url

```
$result = '';
$a = mysql_query("SELECT customer FROM orders GROUP BY customer");
while($b = mysql_fetch_row($a))
 $result.=  $b[0].'<br/>';

 echo "<a href=user.php?zakaz=$result></a>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для цикла надо было создать блок, я так думаю :)

```
$result = '';
$a = mysql_query("SELECT customer FROM orders GROUP BY customer");
while($b = mysql_fetch_row($a)) {
   $result = $b[0].'<br/>';
   echo '<a href=user.php?zakaz=',$result,'>1</a>';
}
```

**А еще бы посоветовал:**

- переходить на [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php);
- не писать в двойных кавычках переменную;
- и использовать ассоциативный массив строк;
- в тег а все таки помещать какой нибудь текст.

Comment: во то что надо, а вот вместо еденицы как бы сделать что бы сама запись из базы была?

Comment: все разобрался)
 echo '<a href=user.php?zakaz='.$result.'>'.$result.'</a><br/>';